# Any software to compare text in PDF for various languages?

Tags: pdf

Does anyone know of any Windows compatible software that will allow me to compare two different PDF files.

Preferably one that can highlight the differences.

Answer (score 0):

[DiffPDF](http://www.qtrac.eu/diffpdf.html) is used to compare two PDF files—textually or visually.

[image]